# HTTP GET Request returns spaces

Tags: jsp, get, newline

I have a GET request to a jsp page. The contents of the JSP page is below:

```
<%@page language="java" import="java.sql.*,java.util.*" %>
<%@page import="javax.servlet.*, java.util.*,java.util.Date, java.text.*"%>
<jsp:useBean id="workM" class="test.concept" scope="page" />
<jsp:useBean id="userM" class="test.learning" scope="page" />
<jsp:useBean id="checkM" class="test.check" scope="session" />
<%
if (checkM.checkUser()) //For auto loading user's most used search engine. Note: Only if the difference between top two is very big
{
    String user_id = checkM.getUser();
    ResultSet RS6=workM.executeQuery("select top 1 searchEngineUsed,count(*) as number from UserSearchEngineSearch where user_id='"+user_id+"' group by searchEngineUsed order by number desc;");
    while (RS6.next())
    {

        String name = RS6.getString("searchEngineUsed");
        if (name.equals("google"))
        {
            out.print("1");
        }
        else if (name.equals("yahoo"))
        {
            out.print("2");
        }
        else if (name.equals("bing"))
        {

            out.print("3");
        }
        else if (name.equals("baidu"))
        {

            out.print("4");
        }
        else if (name.equals("yandex"))
        {
            out.print("5");
        }
        else if (name.equals("askcom"))
        {
            out.print("6");
        }
        else //by default just display google
        {
            out.print("1");
        }
    }
}
else //user not login
{ 
    out.print("1");
}
%>
```

However, the content of the GET webpage is contains 5 lines of new line followed by a 4 (which means "baidu" was selected). How do I remove the 5 lines of new line spacing?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Tomcat you could use

```
<%@ page trimDirectiveWhitespaces="true" %>
```

on your page, or define a global setting in your `web.xml`

```
<jsp-config>
  <jsp-property-group>
    <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
    <trim-directive-whitespaces>true</trim-directive-whitespaces>
  </jsp-property-group>
</jsp-config>
```

Comment: I'm using Tomcat yes. Will try out this method.

Answer (score 0):

The `<%@page>` and `<jsp:useBean>` directives at the top of your JSP are each separated by a newline. If you actually want to remove them, you need to write these in one line. Yet the extra newlines do not harm, they are not rendered by browsers.

Comment: Ahh this is where I went wrong..Thanks man..No wonder there are 6 newlines.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can rewrite it on to something like this :

```
<%@page language="java" import="java.sql.*,java.util.*"
%><%@page import="javax.servlet.*, java.util.*,java.util.Date, java.text.*"
%><jsp:useBean id="workM" class="test.concept" scope="page" 
/><jsp:useBean id="userM" class="test.learning" scope="page" 
/><jsp:useBean id="checkM" class="test.check" scope="session"
/><%
......
%>
```

It will not add any extra new lines.

Comment: Ahh this is where I went wrong..Thanks man!